# How to write and save changes to “/etc/fstab” after effectively breaking the “/etc/fstab” on my system. Can only boot to basic terminal

Tags: linux, mount, linux-mint, fstab

To make a long story short, and to focus the question, I basically need to get root access to my own laptop running Linux Mint to be able to save my changes to the `/etc/fstab` file.

#### More details:

I'm writing this on my phone because I think I broke my computer.

I dual boot Windows 10 and Linux Mint Cinnamon and I wanted my Linux partition to be shared between both operating systems. So I edited `/etc/fstab` to allow this, but I should have left the file path alone because now I broke it. Originally the file path was just `/` but I changed it to `/home/will/shared` thinking that this works like `subst` in Windows (it does not).

When I restarted in Linux it didn't show the desktop but instead showed a primitive looking terminal. There was an error message but it went away so fast I couldn't get a picture in time. Said something about GRUB, I think that's the bootloader so it might be relevant

I thought if I change `/etc/fstab` back to how I had it, everything would be fixed, but when I try to save it says the file is read only.

`sudo editor /etc/fstab` won't let me save it, so how do I revert my changes?

Here is a screenshot of the `/etc/fstab` itself.

[image: Screenshot of the /etc/fstab content.]

Here is a screenshot of the terminal I see when I boot now. The text reads:

```
Linux Mint 20.2 Uma will-HP-Laptop-14-dk1xxx tty1
will-HP-Laptop-14-dk1xxx login:
```

[image: Screenshot of the terminal I see when I boot now.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See if you can boot the machine into single user mode and edit the `/etc/fstab` without issue.

If you can boot the system into single user mode, that is effectively the same as logging in as `root` so you can just then edit your `/etc/fstab` and undo the mistake. Then just reboot and all should one fine.

Here are more details on how to do that as explained [in this answer to a similar issue on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44033/30848):

> It seems that I’ve found a solution:
>
> - At the GRUB prompt, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to append options.
> - Add `init=/bin/bash` to the end of the kernel command line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
> The system will boot to a prompt like `bash-3.2#` enter the following commands at the prompt
>
> ```
> mount -o remount,rw /
> ```
>
> Then edit the fstab:
>
> ```
> vim /etc/fstab
> ```
>
> Edit the fstab file commenting the errors by adding a # at the begining of each problematic line, save the file and reboot by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.